# Show failover status on BIG-IP® Configuration Utility login page?

Tags: f5

We have our F5 LTM BIG-IP® Configuration Utility setup in an Active/Passive setup, and have different links to each admin utility console.

Is it possible to display the Failover Status (active vs standby) on the Login Page so you don't have to login to see the status?  It's frustrating to login only to see you've logged into the Standby node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, but if you go to System>Preferences you could modify the "Security Banner Text To Show On The Login Screen". Generally, here you would specify a custom security message which provides legal protection to your organization, such as a message stating that unauthorized access is forbidden and what password restriction that other users should be specifying (the login screen of the BIG-IP Configuration utility displays the text that you specify in this field). Here, you could probably mention which is active and which is standby without syncing this change to the group. Just make sure that whenever you fail-over from one device to the other (shouldn't be too often); that you simply adjust this message and you should therefore be good to go with that. Hope this helps :)

https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-datacenter-firewall-config-11-1-0/3.html